# Groovy: Compile + Embed

Tags: java, groovy

The goal is

1. Start with a scripting language that uses Groovy for preprocessor directives (entire preprocessor langauge)
2. Parse that script with Antlr 4 (surround regular script with prints and strip # for groovy and output as a Groovy script)
3. Compile the Groovy script in an embedded java application (Groovy should be able to access the classes etc in that application)
4. Load that script at a later time during another compilation of a script when that script wants to use the compiled Groovy (like a project using a dll). When loading, the Groovy script will run and generate code (remember the print statements?) that is specific to the user's project.

Why do I want to compile it? These external resources (essentially dlls) don't need to be parsed over and over again when they are being used by an end user in their project. I want them to be in a ready to go state.

My first idea was to serialize the AST generated by Antlr to binary and then load it back up, but I realized that a compiled Groovy script would be much smarter.

The question is, how do I save the compilation that Groovy makes when dynamically loading a script, and then load it up at a later time?

Any help toward an answer would be much appreciated =).

Comment: Do you want your compiled script to interact with arbitrary Groovy classes supplied later that don't implement an interface known at compilation time? Because if so, I'm not sure that's possible.

Comment: The groovy class (script A) should inherit from a known interface. Script B, the Groovy script wantin to use Script A, should be able to interact with Script A later on. Script A is compiled dynamically and then saved somehow, and the class in it inherits from a known interface. Script B, later on (maybe a week later) wants to use the compiled Script A, so script A is imported into B. Script B is then compiled (keeping A separate).